# Regular Expression to retrieve length

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I want to retrieval number of length, such as 12m, 12 m, 3,2 meters but don't get the value of areas 3m2 or 3m3  .... I use the regular expression to get value. This is my regular expression but it's not run. :(

```
([0-9]+[,.]*[0-9]*\s*(mét|m|cm|dm|mm|km|hm|dam|centimet)+(^[0-9]+))*
```

Comment: Please show examples for all measurements, and also show that data inside the text which you plan to use.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/1whTrz/1 seems to be working, but without some examples I don't know the goal.

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/I7mVoS/1

Comment: What is `(^[0-9]+)` supposed to do?  I'm guessing this is wrong.  First of all, `^` outside of square brackets means to match the beginning of the string, which won't work.  Second, if you put it inside the brackets, like `([^0-9]+), it will match a character that isn't a digit--but it has to match a character.  If you're at the end of the string, eg. `12m`, then it will fail because it's not matching any character.  To say "I don't want to see a digit here", use _negative lookahead_.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[0-9]+([,.][0-9]*)?\s*(mét|m|cm|dm|mm|km|hm|dam|centimet)\s*([^\s0-9]|\z)
```

Explanation:

- Match 1 or more digits
- Optionally match a comma or dot followed by zero or more digits.
- Match zero or more spaces.
- Match a unit string.
- Match zero or more spaces
- Match either a character that's not a digit or space or end of input.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach (every test passing):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RemoveUnitSpec {
    public static String removeUnit(String input) {     
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                return input.substring(0, i).trim();
            }
        }
        return input;
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldDoNothingWhenNoUnit() {
        String input = "3,52";

        assertEquals("3,52", removeUnit(input));
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldRemoveUnit() {
        String input = "12m";

        assertEquals("12", removeUnit(input));
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldRemoveSquareMeter() {
        String input = "12m2";

        assertEquals("12", removeUnit(input));
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldRemoveUnitWithSpace() {
        String input = "12 m";

        assertEquals("12", removeUnit(input));
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldRemoveTextualUnitWithSpace() {
        String input = "3,2 meters";

        assertEquals("3,2", removeUnit(input));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use something like so:

```
([0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]*)?)\s*(mét|m|cm|dm|mm|km|hm|dam|centimet)([0-9]+)?
```

You can then obtain each part of the string as follows:

```
Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(string);
if (matcher.matches) {
    String value = matcher.group(1);
    String unit = matcher.group(2);
    String exp = matcher.group(3); // may be null
    ...
}
```